# Jump boundary conditions

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, physics

I'm having the following issue that can not find a solution , by using this boundary condition

```
 u[0, t] == 1,
 v[0, t] == u[1, t],
 w[0, t] == v[1, t],
 z[0, t] == w[1, t]
```

that Mathematica does not understand, someone please help me!

```
s = NDSolve[
  {
   D[u[x, t], t] == -D[u[x, t], x] - 1 v[x, t] w[x, t] z[x, t],
   D[v[x, t], t] == -D[v[x, t], x] - 2 u[x, t] w[x, t] z[x, t],
   D[w[x, t], t] == -D[w[x, t], x] - 3 u[x, t] v[x, t] z[x, t],
   D[z[x, t], t] == -D[z[x, t], x] - 4 u[x, t] v[x, t] w[x, t],

   u[x, 0] == 1,
   v[x, 0] == 2,
   w[x, 0] == 3,
   z[x, 0] == 4,

   u[0, t] == 1,
   v[0, t] == u[1, t],
   w[0, t] == v[1, t],
   z[0, t] == w[1, t]
   },

  {u[x, t], v[x, t], w[x, t], z[x, t]},

  {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}]
```

I'm getting this error message :

NDSolve::bcedge: Boundary condition v[0,t]==u[1,t] is not specified on a single edge of the boundary of the computational domain. >>

I have already presented a similar problem here, but the reasoning suggested is not a good solution for my case.

What strategies do you know to treat this problem ? I appreciate any help...

Comment: not sure why the downvote.  Anyway `NDSolve` is not so general that it can handle any sort of bc you can dream up, even if mathematically valid.  In this case the pde's look to be fully decoupled, so solve first for `u`, then use that solution as a bc as you solve for `v` and so on.  Alternately formulate as a single unknown on domain `x,0,4`

Comment: Thank you. But I need to solve all equations at once.

Comment: I'm afraid you will need to work out your own finite difference scheme.

Comment: How you could do this, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by the [Documentation Center](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/message/NDSolve/bcedge.html), you can  remove excess (last 3) conditions.

```
s = NDSolve[{D[u[x, t], t] == -D[u[x, t], x] - u[x, t], 
    D[v[x, t], t] == -D[v[x, t], x] - v[x, t], 
    D[w[x, t], t] == -D[w[x, t], x] - w[x, t], 
    D[z[x, t], t] == -D[z[x, t], x] - z[x, t],
    u[x, 0] == 1, v[x, 0] == 1, w[x, 0] == 1,
    z[x, 0] == 1, u[0, t] == 1},
  {u[x, t], v[x, t], w[x, t], z[x, t]}, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}];

Plot3D[Evaluate[u[x, t] /. s[[1, 1]]], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}]
Plot3D[Evaluate[v[x, t] /. s[[1, 2]]], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}]
Plot3D[Evaluate[w[x, t] /. s[[1, 3]]], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}]
Plot3D[Evaluate[z[x, t] /. s[[1, 4]]], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}]
```

Will give you the solutions.

Comment: Thus the boundary conditions for the other variables are wrong because the ultilizados values ​​in the solution does not match the proposed problem .

Answer (score 0):

A method to solve the original decoupled system :

```
s = NDSolve[{
   D[u[x, t], t] == -D[u[x, t], x] - u[x, t],
   u[x, 0] == 1,
   u[0, t] == 1}, {u[x, t]}, {x, 0, 4}, {t, 0, 1}]
v[x_, t_] = (u[x, t] /. s[[1, 1]]) /. x -> x + 1;
w[x_, t_] = (u[x, t] /. s[[1, 1]]) /. x -> x + 2;
z[x_, t_] = (u[x, t] /. s[[1, 1]]) /. x -> x + 3;
Row[{
  ContourPlot[u[x, t] /. s[[1, 1]], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}],
  ContourPlot[v[x, t], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}],
  ContourPlot[w[x, t], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}],
  ContourPlot[z[x, t], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. But I need to solve all equations at once. 
The example it is simple , but the truth is that each variable has its own distinct equation among others.